# Eclipse CNF, double-click action to open a view

Tags: eclipse, rcp, cnf

I'd like to be able to double-click on a file with a specific extension in the eclipse project explorer and for it to open a read-only view of the associated file.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be most appreciated.

Thanks, Steve